# How does the diameter have any effect on the first harmonic frequency?

Tags: waves, frequency

[image]

The answer is C. What I don't understand is how the diameter would have any effect on the first harmonic frequency as the formula $$f=\frac{1}{2L}\sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}}$$

Comment: Doesn't a wire of larger diameter have more mass per unit length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is that $\mu$ is the *linear* density of the string, i.e. the mass per unit length. Both strings are made of the same material, so they have the same density $\rho$. The mass of a cylinder of density $\rho$, length $L$, and diameter $d$ is $\frac{\pi}{4}\rho d^2L$. This means that the linear density is

$$\mu=\frac{m}{L}=\frac{\pi}{4}\rho d^2$$

Comment: Thanks this one makes sense! So the height in this case would be the length of the wire right? Which the volume in this case would be a cylinder.

Answer (score 3):

The diameter of the string affects the linear mass density $\mu$, which measures the mass per unit length.